# Why my chained methods with boost::future's .then are not invoked?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, future

I have the following piece of code:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int foo(boost::future<int> x) {
  std::cout << "first stage(" << x.get() << ")" << '\n';
  return x.get();
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "making promise" << '\n';
  boost::promise<int> p;
  boost::future<int> f = p.get_future();
  std::cout << "future chain made" << '\n';
  std::thread t([&](){
    f.then(foo)
      .then([](boost::future<int> x){ std::cout << "second stage " << 2 * x.get() << '\n'; return 2 * x.get(); })
      .then([](boost::future<int> x){ std::cout << "final stage " << 10 * x.get() << '\n'; });
  });

  std::cout << "fulfilling promise" << '\n';
  p.set_value(42);
  std::cout << "promise fulfilled" << '\n';

  t.join();
}
```

and I compile it like so:

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -DBOOST_THREAD_VERSION=4 main.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system -pthread
```

and I get the following output:

```
making promise
future chain made
fulfilling promise
promise fulfilled
first stage(42)
```

Why my 2 lambdas chained in thread `t` not invoked? Am I missing something?

I have tried adding `boost::future::get()` call but I get an exception then:

```
  std::cout << "fulfilling promise" << '\n';
  p.set_value(42);
  std::cout << "promise fulfilled" << '\n';

  std::cout << "value " << f.get() << '\n';

  t.join();
```

error:

```
making promise
future chain made
fulfilling promise
promise fulfilled
first stage(42)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::future_uninitialized> >'
  what():  Operation not permitted on an object without an associated state.
[1]    20875 abort      ./main
```

I am using boost 1.58.0 and gcc 5.4.0

Online source link ( with booost 1.58.0 and gcc 5.3.0) http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/G8rqt2eHUwI4nzz8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a great poet once wrote, "wait for it".

```
std::thread t([&](){
  f.then(foo)
  .then([](boost::shared_future<int> x){ std::cout << "second stage " << 2 * x.get() << '\n'; return 2 * x.get(); })
  .then([](boost::shared_future<int> x){ std::cout << "final stage " << 10 * x.get() << '\n'; })
  .get();
});
```

The thread does nothing but set up a chain of futures.  It does not run any of them.

You start the chain (with your set), and you wait for the chain to be set up (with join), but main exits before thr chain is complete.  You get "lucky", with one running before process exit.

Really, you should be setting up the chain in the main thread and waiting on the last future from the chain in your thread t.  Then your code makes more sense.

```
auto last = f.then(foo)
  .then([](boost::shared_future<int> x){ std::cout << "second stage " << 2 * x.get() << '\n'; return 2 * x.get(); })
  .then([](boost::shared_future<int> x){ std::cout << "final stage " << 10 * x.get() << '\n'; });

std::thread t([&](){
  last.get();
});
```

This highlights the fact that the thread t does not serve a useful purpose: replace `t.join()` with `last.get()` in the main thread and delete the variable `t` entirely.

As noted below in comments, you are also calling get twice: for that to work, you need a shared_future.  This is probably why your luck wws consistent, as the second get may block up the threads.

Comment: With `std::future` it is illegal to call `get()` more than once; is the same true for `boost::future`? (The assertion I get when running this suggests so, but the documentation doesn't make it clear to me...)

Comment: @Yakk You're right but both of us missed a very important point in my code: I was calling `x.get()` in callbacks twice which is UB.

Comment: @pat folded that in.  If they where `std` the implicit cast to shared future from rvalue future makes the fix easy: assuming boost is as smart.